# CSS3 columns space bottom

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, layout

We are trying to create a menu style layout. I'm using a css-columns properties to achieve the effect of columns. The content is variable, so we'd like to stick to this solution because we want the browser to organise the content for best fit.

In the example below we are seeing some odd behaviour in Chrome (Version 32.0.1700.77) and some different (but equally odd) issue in Firefox (Version 24.0) so I'm assuming it's our implementation.

In Chrome, we see a large gap underneath the first column as if it's placing the 3rd LI there to start off with, then moving it to the top of the second column at some point in the render process.

In Firefox, we see the H3 "scrambled egg" being left at the bottom of the first column, when the rest of the 3rd LI's content moved to the top of the second column.

Live Example: http://codepen.io/daviddarnes/pen/BeEIp

Speculations: 
- We are using "break-inside: avoid;" on every element inside the OL. This could be causing the issue, but we can't seem to rectify it.
- Based on the H3 issue... might be something to do with that? Or the elements near to this H3 tag.

Comment: Also tried in firefox 26.0 and the H3 detached. Not sure if this is the same release as funnelcake, but tried that one and it seems to work fine.

Comment: Potentially an implementation bug in Chrome and Firefox. Bug raised for Chrome:

https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=337792&q=break-inside%20avoid&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Iteration%20ReleaseBlock%20Cr%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified

Comment: Bug report found in Firefox which has similar symptoms as describe above: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=961268

Answer (score 0):

The point of the page-break properties is not to shrink content to fit on a page, but to help decide the optimal place for a page break to occur.

So, if you use 'page-break-inside:avoid' on an element, and there's not enough space on the current page to fit the entire element, the browser will consider inserting a break so as to force the element onto a new page, theoretically giving it more space.

However, if the element is so big that moving it onto a new page won't help, then there's nothing to be done (in terms of page breaks at least).

If you know in advance that your content will need to be shrunk when printing, you could try adding a scale transform on the problem elements (restricted to the print media type), so that they're a more manageable size.

Is this of any help to you?